# Flexslider with php multiple videos

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, while-loop, flexslider

I have a table "videos" with id_video, client, code. And i found this:

http://demo.juanfra.me/multiple-videos-flexslider-v2/

First i tried put the -li- into a while and show all results with mysqli_fetch_array.
But i cant show anything. I think the id of each iframe "player_number" must be unique, so do i have to use a for()?

```
<?php while($rowmulti = mysqli_fetch_array($resultmultimedia)){
echo'
    <li>
        <iframe id="player_1" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'.$rowmulti["code"].'?api=1&player_id=player_1"></iframe>
    </li>
';}?>
```

Maybe the error is in the jquery code but i dont good js programmer. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a for loop. You can just keep track of an `$id` variable within the loop that increments each iteration.

Try this:

```
<?php
  $id = 1;
  while ($rowmulti = mysqli_fetch_array($resultmultimedia)) {
  echo'
    <li>
      <iframe id="player_' . $id . '" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/' . $rowmulti["code"] . '?api=1&player_id=player_' . $id . '"></iframe>
    </li>';
    $id++;
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! that should work, I edit the code with this but not work. I think the problem is in the code jquery :/

Comment: Hey, now im doing things right, i didnt have any import (froogaloop.js and jquery.fitvid.js) im sorry! Your code works fine! thank you @Aiias